# AWS Athena Convert Seconds to HH:mm:ss

Tags: sql, datetime, presto, amazon-athena, date-arithmetic

How do I in AWS Athena Convert Seconds to HH:mm:ss - this would be similar to SELECT SEC_TO_TIME in MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running Presto, which supports a `time` datatype, you can just do:

```sql
select time '00:00:00' + no_seconds * interval '1' second
```

... where `no_seconds` is the number of seconds you want to convert.

Comment: Thx this works perfectly but now I have another problem. I need to remove the last 2 digits from the integer value before I do the conversion. Should I post another question for this?

Comment: got it :select time '00:00:00' + CAST(SUBSTRING('2614500',1,5)as INTEGER) * interval '1' second